# Laravel 5 is redirecting http to https ? How to disable this?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, laravel-5

A year ago I have done something which i can't remember anymore which allowed me to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS after installing an ssl certificate.

Now I spent 2 days looking for the code which may be causing the redirection and I couldn't find it. it's not on .htaccess and its not a server configuration issue. I looked through instruction to setup ssl so i can reverse them but no luck.

Anyone can tell me how to prevent the site from redirecting to HTTPS.

You can [click here](http://socialfetch.com) to access the website in case that is needed.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to redirect?

Comment: i have this problem too, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an issue with the browser cache as I am not being redirected to HTTPS. You can try clearing your browser cache or opening the page with an incognito window. In any case, I do not get redirected to https when I click the link or any other link on that page.

Comment: Are you using Firefox ?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome, and they both do not get redirected to https.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply edit ".env" file and change 
`FORCE_HTTPS=true` 
to be 
`FORCE_HTTPS=false` 
and change 
`APP_URL = https://example.com` 
to be 
`APP_URL = http://example.com`