# Disable Laravel 8 application redirection from http to https deployed on Xampp Apache server

Tags: php, laravel, apache, https, http-redirect

I want to Disable redirecting from http to https in my Laravel 8 application temporarily due to some issues.
I've tried the solution of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002815/laravel-5-is-redirecting-http-to-https-how-to-disable-this) but didn't work for me.

I have tried the following solution:

- Apache server configurations
- Browser cache clearing
- php artisan optimize:clear
- php artisan route:clear
- .env file

```
   APP_URL="http://example.com"
   FORCE_HTTPS=false2
```

Comment: _"Commented out these two line in public/.htaccess file"_ - those have nothing whatsoever to do with this. (Their purpose is to pass any HTTP Authorization data on via an environment variable.)

Comment: This is for your local development setup, I presume? (Because why would you still have a production website _not_ use HTTPS in this day & age.) What URL are you actually using then? Maybe the redirect is set up at a higher level in your web server configuration?

Comment: since when Laravel started automatic redirecting to https if you haven't setup to to do so!

Comment: @CBroe I have to let both http and https ports run temporarily for some reasons, without redirecting http requests to https for now. The application is deployed on a Windows server.

Comment: @OMiShah This is what was disturbing me. The problem was actually caused by browsers. Once the browser stores an SSL certificate, it attaches the certificate to the site by itself sometimes. This was causing redirection from http to https. Browsers were doing this even in incognito mode.

Comment: _"Once the browser stores an SSL certificate, it attaches the certificate to the site by itself sometimes."_ - but they should not decide to do that on their own; I am guessing that your site was previously served with `HSTS`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security

Comment: @CBroe yes HSTS was enabled before. I have disabled it temporarily due to some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had reverted my Apache server configurations which caused https redirection. But even then, the problem was consistent. Because neither the *Apache server* nor *Laravel* were causing problems.

The problem was actually caused by web browsers. Once the browser stores an SSL certificate, it attaches the certificate to the site by itself sometimes. This was causing redirection from http to https. Browsers were doing this even in incognito mode.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome#:%7E:text=In%20addition%20to%20cached%20redirects,Security%20header%20from%20the%20server) helped me in resolving my problem.

So I deleted the ***domain security policy*** using the following steps and the browser stopped this behavior.

1. Type this in browser URL bar

```
   chrome://net-internals/#hsts
```

2. Deleted my domain name in the section
   **Delete domain security policies**

[image]

3. Clearing browser data **(Cached images and files)**

```
   chrome://settings/clearBrowserData
```

[image: Clear cached images and files]

Comment: _"The problem was actually caused by web browsers."_ - it was caused by using HSTS. The web browsers were simply following your instructions. The point of HSTS is that it applies "into the future."

Comment: Yes, but it was even applying in incognito. And clearing browser data also didn't work. 
So I had to Delete domain security policies. 
BTW thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Yes, this is supposed to persist even if you clear the browsing data/cache, and to apply in incognito as well. With HSTS you are basically saying to the browser, "for this specified amount of time into the future, _always_ use HTTPS to access this site." Of course this backfires then, when you have to disable HTTPS within that specified time frame.